# Scrollview scrolls to bottom of page when footer-ad is loaded

Tags: android, admob, fragment, scrollview

My app has an activity which displays some text under a scroll-view, with ad-fragment at the end of scrolling. The problem is, whenever I open that activity, the page is scrolled suddenly to the bottom as soon as the ad loads.
My layout file content is:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="${packageName}.${activityClass}"
    android:background="@color/black" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:background="@color/darkblue"
        android:text="--single line title here --" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/SCROLLER_ID"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:background="@color/black" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvStory"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:padding="15dp"
                android:background="@color/black"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:text="--multi-page story here --" />

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/adFragment"
                android:name="com.mysite.ReadActivity$AdFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Any help in this regard will be deeply appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I wonder if setting the fragment's height to a fixed value would stop this from happening?

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't work. Thanks anyway, Rich :)

Comment: You are better off economically and technically moving the ad fragment outside the scroll.

Comment: Tried that too, but it started overlapping with the fragment. Finally I had to put it below scrollview using bottom margin, but that's not what I want. I want the ad to show only when the person finishes reading the article.